# Access to one specific object via multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading, pyserial

i'm looking for a solution in order to access to one object by few threads.

I'm actually controlling a robot via a serial port using `pySerial`. I instantiated one class who allows to send data through the serial:

```
ser =  serial.Serial(com, baudrate=38400, timeout=None, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

I plan to have:

- second thread who ask the robot position.
- one thread who send the moving instructions
- second thread who ask the robot position.

Obviously the threads can't access the object (serial port communication) `self.ser` at the same time.

What would be the best solution(s)? The  object `ser` would act like a "singleton", how do I lock the thread when one is accessing to it ?

Would it be possible to have something who look like this :

```
ser =  serial.Serial(com, baudrate=38400, timeout=None, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
robot=myRobot(...)
t1=Trajectory(csv_file,'COM5',q,ser,robot)
t2=postionUpdate(ser,robot)
t1.start()
```

Comment: Take a look at locks in the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module.

Comment: In a nutshell, create a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects) and make each thread acquire it before using the port (and release it when they're finished). This means the what you have at the end would not be possible unless you created some sort of proxy for the did the locking internally but provided the same interface as `ser`.